# php sql syntax error in function while inserting data

Tags: php

this is the functuion to clean html

but its showing following errors:

```
function cleanHTML($input){
    $blank_letter = array('â„¢','Â','âˆž','â€¢',"â€");
    $output = str_replace($blank_letter, '', $input);
    $output = str_replace('â€™', '\'', $output);
    $output = str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $input);
    $output = preg_replace('/\s/', '', $output);
    $output = str_replace('...', '', $output);
    $output = str_replace("'", '', $output);
    $output = ltrim($output);
    $output = rtrim($output);
    return $output;
    echo var_dump($output);
}
```

> INSERT INTO `productrawdata` (`shopid`, `ProviderProductId`, `ProviderCategory` , `ProviderUrl`, `Name`, `Description` , `BrandName`, `ProductPrice`, `ShippingTime` , `ShippingCost`, `ImageUrl`, `ImageTitle` , `ImageExt`, `UniqueBatchId`, `active`) VALUES ('Flipkart', '83e4969015264d2e4759648895c30e2f', 'Camera', 'http://dl.flipkart.com/dl/gadget-hero-s-sports-camera-ghxsc786w-body-only-action/p/itmeabsvzheaatzu?pid=CAMEABSVJZBA4WTG' ,'GadgetHerosSportsCameraGHXSC786WBodyOnlySports&ActionCamera(White)','GadgetHerosSportsCameraGHXSC786WBodyOnlySports&ActionCamera (White)', 'Gadget Hero's' ,'7950', '', ' ' ,'http://img.fkcdn.com/image/camera/w/t/g/gadget-hero-s-sports-camera-ghxsc786w-sports-action-200x200-imaea8h3mpsgpggw.jpeg', 'gadget-hero-s-sports-camera-ghxsc786w-sports-action-200x200-imaea8h3mpsgpggw','jpeg', '9fa420a2edb3e8de128e011f4d11c15d', '1');

Comment: Please provide details of query.

Comment: it is not the function which produce the error, there is another lines

Comment: Oh boy... "clean HTML"... I don't even know where to start here... Get rid of this garbage, start from scratch. Having such a function anywhere in your codebase is a big red flag.

Comment: When it comes to HTML in the database it's better to validate it on input and escape it on output.

Comment: means what should be done?

Comment: Rethink your entire approach. You seem to have 1) encoding problems, 2) escaping problems, 3) mythical believes about "cleanliness". Perhaps start here: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 0):

- You need make choise between return output or echo :)
- You forget to change the variable $input by $output on the line .5
- You made $output between ''!!

  ```
  $output = str_replace("'", '', $output);
  ```

  This line erase the effect of those lines before it:

  ```
  $output = str_replace('â€™', '\'', $output);
  $output = preg_replace('\'/\\s/\'', ', \'\',', '$output');
  ```

Try this :

```
function cleanHTML($input){
    $blank_letter = array('â„¢','Â','âˆž','â€¢',"â€","...");
    $output = str_replace($blank_letter, '', $input);
    $output = str_replace('â€™', '\'', $output);
    $output = str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $output);
    $output = preg_replace('\'/\\s/\'', ', \'\',', $output);
    $output = ltrim($output);
    $output = rtrim($output);
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: insert error cleared but now it shows the following error:    Update Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's state-of-the-art DIGIC 5 image processing technology makes it possible to capt' at line 2

Comment: $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `productrawdata` (`shopid`, `ProviderProductId`, `ProviderCategory         , `ProviderUrl`, `Name`, `Description       , `BrandName`, `ProductPrice`, `ShippingTime`             VALUES ('{$shopid}', '{$ProviderProductId}', '{$ProviderCategory}', '{$ProviderUrl}               ,'{$Name}', '{$Description}', '{$BrandName}    ,'{$ProductPrice}', '{$ShippingTime}', '{$ShippingCost}'             or die('Insert Error: ' .mysql_error());  
$ImageData = null;

Comment: yes the update request and the data your are inserting

Comment: mysql_query("UPDATE `productrawdata` SET `active`='0'        WHERE `shopid` = '{$shopid}' and `ProviderCategory` = '{$ProviderCategory}' and `UniqueBatchId` != '{$UniqueBatchId}';") or die('Update Error: ' .mysql_error());

Comment: I think you need to check the input data, apply addslashes() to string vars before updating

Comment: sorry but I did not understand.

Comment: $ProviderCategory = addslashes($ProviderCategory);
mysql_query("UPDATE productrawdata SET active='0' WHERE shopid = '{$shopid}' and ProviderCategory = '{$ProviderCategory}' and UniqueBatchId != '{$UniqueBatchId}';") or die('Update Error: ' .mysql_error());

Comment: can you provide the values of the variables passed on the request

Comment: VALUES ('{$shopid}', '{$ProviderProductId}', '{$ProviderCategory}', '{$ProviderUrl}'
                 ,'{$Name}', '{$Description}', '{$BrandName}'
                 ,'{$ProductPrice}', '{$ShippingTime}', '{$ShippingCost}'
                 ,'{$ImageUrl}', '{$ImageTitle}', '{$ImageExt}', '{$ImageData}', '{$UniqueBatchId}', '{$IsActive}', '{$OriginalPrice}', '{$Rating}', '{$totalusersrated}');") or die('Insert Error: ' .mysql_error());

Comment: Not that, i mean the value (the content) of variables like $ProviderCategory...
you have error near 's state-of-the-art DIGIC 5 image processing technology makes it possible to capt'

Comment: /dl/canon-eos-5d-mark-iii-body-only-dslr-camera/p/itmd8yvyfdzg6z5x?pid=CAMD8YVYNYZZRWQ5
Shopid : Flipkart
category : Flipkart_Camera
ProviderProductId : 6da3e3b6e42e980b3d8baacacbc2d9c2
ProviderCategory : Camera
ProviderUrl : http://dl.flipkart.com/dl/canon-eos-5d-mark-iii-body-only-dslr-camera/p/itmd8yvyfdzg6z5x?pid=CAMD8YVYNYZZRWQ5
Name : Canon EOS 5D Mark III (Body only) DSLR Camera
Description::The EOS 5D Mark III is part of the world famous EOS range of high performance DSLR cameras from Canon. Offering a staggering array of improved features, higher-speeds, greater resolution and extende

Comment: i would like check the specific input of this string 's state-of-the-art DIGIC 5 image processing technology makes it possible to capt'
did you try mysql_real_escape_string ?

Comment: `Description`='{$row['Description']}',Description::The EOS 5D Mark III is part of the world famous EOS range of high performance DSLR cameras from Canon. Offering a staggering array of improved features, higher-speeds, greater resolution and extended creative options in both image and video departments, the EOS 5D Mark III is sure to provide unmatched artistic freedom for the most demanding and quality conscious photographer. Housing a 36 x 24 mm full . The advent of Canon's state-of-the-art DIGIC 5 image processing technology makes it possible to capture extremely clear high resolution images

Comment: try mysql_real_escape_string on the description var, because you need to add backslash before ( 's state-of-the-art DIGIC 5)

Comment: 'Description`='mysql_real_escape_string({$row['Description']})     like this??

Comment: $description = mysql_real_escape_string($row['Description']);
then
Description='{$description}'

Comment: $description = mysql_real_escape_string($row['Description']);
   $result = mysql_query("UPDATE `productrawdata` SET `shopid`='{$row['shopid']}', `ProviderCategory`='{$row['ProviderCategory']}'
        , `ProviderUrl`='{$row['ProviderUrl']}', `Name`='{$row['Name']}'
        , `Description`='{$row['$description']}', still give same error

Comment: Hehe your fanny :D
Try this...
$description = mysql_real_escape_string($row['Description']); $result = mysql_query("UPDATE productrawdata SET shopid='{$row['shopid']}', ProviderCategory='{$row['ProviderCategory']}' , ProviderUrl='{$row['ProviderUrl']}', Name='{$row['Name']}' , Description='{$description}'